# Normal equation in linear regression return theta coefficients as 'NaN'

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, nan, linear-regression

I am trying to do linear regression using **normal equation** method. In my data I have **n = 143** features and **m = 13000** training examples. I know that normal equation method is **not** recommended when number of features greater than 10000. But I have only 143 features. My code return `'nan'` as my array of thetas (linear coefficients).

In my csv file data presented without headers. So my data in csv file looks like this (only first 15 training examples and without column of ones yet):

```
2;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;1986;9;1;16;5;1;1.65;1;0;0;0;4;2;1;0;0;0;1;1;0;0;0;0;2.8;1;0;15000
2;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;6;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;2006;8;0;23;5;2;1.65;1;0;0;0;2;2.23;1;0;0;0;1;1;0;0;0;0;2.79;1;0;12900
1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;4;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;1987;6;0;29;6;2;1;0;1;0;0;2;1;0;1;0;0;2.12;0;1;0;0;0;2.8;3;0;23438
2;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;2009;3;0;56;5;3;1;1;0;0;0;4;2;1;0;0;0;2;1;0;0;0;0;2.79;1;0;67000
1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;10;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;1978;5;1;115;6;2;2;1;0;0;0;4;2;1;0;0;0;3;0;1;0;0;0;2.8;3;0;230000
3;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;6;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;2006;7;0;250;4.93;4;4;1;0;0;0;3.91;2.23;0;0;1;0;2.12;0;0;1;0;0;3;2;0;224000
1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;8;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;2007;3;0;31;5;2;1;1;0;0;0;3.91;2.23;0;1;0;0;2.12;0;1;0;0;0;2.79;1;0;45000
1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;4;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;1975;8;1;31;6;3;2;1;0;0;0;4;2;1;0;0;0;2;0;1;0;0;0;2.79;2;0;66000
1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;5;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;1992;1;1;32;5;2.52;1.65;0;1;0;0;3.91;2.23;0;1;0;0;2.12;0;0;1;0;0;2.79;1;0;34000
1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;2012;16;1;32;5;2;2;1;0;0;0;4;2;1;0;0;0;2;1;0;0;0;0;2.79;1;0;36000
2;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;8;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;1977;3;0;33;6;2;1.65;1;0;0;0;4;2.23;0;1;0;0;2.12;0;1;0;0;0;2.79;1;0;38000
2;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;8;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;2007;3;0;33;4.93;2;1;1;0;0;0;4;2.23;0;1;0;0;2.12;1;0;0;0;0;2.79;2;0;37000
1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;8;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;1990;3;0;33;5;2;1;1;0;0;0;4;2;1;0;0;0;2;1;0;0;0;0;2.79;1;0;38000
2;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;8;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;2012;4;0;33;5;2;2;1;0;0;0;4;4;1;0;0;0;2;1;0;0;0;0;2.79;1;0;45000
3;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;7;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;1982;1;1;35;5;2;1.65;1;0;0;0;4;2.23;0;0;0;1;2;1;0;0;0;0;2.7;1;0;45000
```

*Note:* *The reason why data contain so many zeros and ones is because I used dummy coding for some features. Some features have decent number of classes.*

---

Python Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

path = 'DB2.csv'  
data = pd.read_csv(path, header=None, delimiter=";")

data.insert(0, 'Ones', 1)

print np.linalg.cond(data)
print np.linalg.matrix_rank(data)

cols = data.shape[1] 
X = data.iloc[:,0:cols-1]  
y = data.iloc[:,cols-1:cols] 

#Normal equation:
xTx = X.T.dot(X)
XtX = np.linalg.inv(xTx)
XtX_xT = XtX.dot(X.T)
theta = XtX_xT.dot(y)

print theta
```

---

This formula used for normal equation:

[image]

Output of the program (array of thetas):

```
[[ nan]
 [ nan]
 [ nan]
 [ nan]
 [ nan]
 ...
 [ nan]]
```

Also in the program I tried to check **condition number** of matrix by the code:

```
print np.linalg.cond(data)
```

This line of code also returned `'nan'`

But this line of code for checking **matrix rank**:

```
print np.linalg.matrix_rank(data)
```

Returned **0**.

---

I need some clarification of what is going on. I cannot figure out what is wrong and why I get `nan`.

Comment: What happens when you print the sum of each column using np.sum? Any NaNs there?

Comment: No Nans in this case. np.sum correctly return sum of elements in a column

Comment: xTx = X.T.dot(X) has no NaNs either?  And then what's condition number of xTx? singular values of xTx?  rank of xTx? Is xTx basically singular?

Comment: For now I resolved problem of getting NaNs. Now I received values of condition number and rank: CN: 7.13391822002e+22
Rank: 132

Comment: It really seem to be a problem of matrix being singular. I have to do regularization.

Comment: Check my answer...  perhaps you might have full dummy variables for multiple categories?

Comment: Cross-posted at Stats.SE, where folks there pointed out an answer (it's a dup): http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/185735/2921

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something to watch out for when using dummy/indicator variables, and *might* be happening here:

#### Including a constant vector + full indicators (or multiple categories with full indicators) creates a rank deficient data matrix

Imagine you have a dummy variable for night, a dummy variable for day, a dummy variable for snowing, and a dummy for not snowing. Your data may be something like:

```
           I_day    I_night     I_snow     I_no_snow
obs 1:         1          0          1             0
obs 2:         0          1          1             0
obs 3:         1          0          0             1
obs 4:         0          1          0             1
etc...
```

A subtle but *HORRIBLE* error has been made, the data matrix is *rank deficient*!   `I_day + I_night` is always a vector of 1s and the same thing for `I_snow + I_no_snow`. We have linear dependence: `I_day+I_night = I_snow+I_no_snow`! The data matrix is rank 3, not rank 4. X'*X will be rank 3 (instead of 4).

#### What to do:

- If including a constant in the data matrix X, then for *each categorical variable* you always need to leave the dummy for 1 category out of the matrix X. (And the dummies will indicate an effect relative to this left out category).

In this example, I could form my data matrix X as follows:

```
           const    I_day     I_snow 
obs 1:         1        1          1
obs 2:         1        0          1
obs 3:         1        1          0
obs 4:         1        0          0
etc...
```

- If no constant is included, you can include *full* dummies for *exactly one* categorical variable.

The basic idea is that you should only have 1 constant vector in your data matrix. Full dummies for 2+ categories is like including 2+ constant vectors in your data matrix.

Answer (score 1):

It would help to have the actual data to see what is really going on, but from what you describe, your data matrix, i.e. X is ill conditioned. Consequently, the condition estimate returns NaN and your rank is 0. Therefore (X^T*X) cannot be inverted. 
To solve this, you need to regularize, i.e compute

(X^T*X+lambda * 1)^(-1)*X^T instead, where 1 is the identity matrix of appropriate dimensions and lambda is your regularization parameter.

Comment: I looked through regularization. The only question I have is why in some formulas in internet it is indeed required to put regularization parameter lambda multipled by identity matrix but in lecture of Andrew Ng he used lambda as well but multiplied it by not quite identity matrix. Formula of Andrew Ng is here at the end of the page: http://napitupulu-jon.appspot.com/posts/Regularized-Linear-Regression.html.  Why he has zero at 1 element of identity matrix?

Comment: That depends on the particular problem, but generally, you would regularize all elements. In your case, with rank 0, you should check your data though, before regularizing, because you would only get that if X is all zeros.